# Method for logging errors and warnings in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm an intern who is making a billing database for a new market that my company is in.  I have created all the tables, and have set up an automatic way to grab and import the data.  However, the method of importing is sort of brute force and not very elegant, because I've only had like 2 weeks to work on it.

1. I have linked tables set up in the database to CSV files
2. I have append queries that will add new records to existing tables.  Warnings are thrown for duplicate entries, but those can be ignored.

What my company wants to do is every day run a program I created to download these reports, on a rolling interval of about 30 days.  Then add any new records into the Access database.

Since I'm leaving soon, I won't have time to test this database, and would like to have some method of documenting errors and warnings that are thrown;  everything from a duplicate entry warning to a type mismatch error, or a syntax error in some SQL query.  Is this possible and if so what do you think would be the most effective way to go about it?  Maybe while my import macro is running open up an error handling function? We are working in Access 2007 if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write to a text file, for the most part, in the error handling routine for each relevant procedure. You may need to watch out for the more serious errors and do something else with them. You will also probably need to watch out for DAO errors, not quite the same thing as code errors (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/HV080753531.aspx). There may be other errors that you wish to raise yourself:

```
Err.Raise vbObjectError + 100
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241678(v=vs.60).aspx

```
LogError (ErrNo & " " & ErrDescr & " " & ErrInfo)

Sub LogError(strError)
Const ForAppending = 8
Dim strPath As String
Dim fs As Object
Dim a As Object

    strPath = GetDataDirectory

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fs.FileExists(strPath & "\ErrorLog.txt") = True Then
        Set a = fs.OpenTextFile(strPath & "\ErrorLog.txt", ForAppending)
    Else
        Set a = fs.createtextfile(strPath & "\ErrorLog.txt")
    End If
    a.WriteLine Date + Time & " " & strError
    a.Close

    Set fs = Nothing
End Sub
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221208(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: +1, you could also adopt a method similar to this to write the errors to a table rather than a text file if someone has background access to view it.

Comment: @Matt I think I would avoid using the application itself for several reasons including finding out the last thing that was logged before it fell apart and the simplicity of emailing a text file.

Comment: Just a thought in case the application is a multi user environment, could the text file become locked on multiple user errors at the same time?

Comment: @Matt I do not know, but I guess it is possible, however if you have so many users and so many errors, I think you have more to worry about than a text file locking.